# Docker: Write to disk of linked container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker container that runs a simple web application. That container is linked to two other containers by Docker Compose with the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongo_service:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  tomcat_service:
    image: 'bitnami/tomcat:latest'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

  web:
    # gain access to linked containers
    links:
      - mongo_service
      - tomcat_service
    # explicitly declare service dependencies
    depends_on:
      - mongo_service
      - tomcat_service
    # set environment variables
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
    # use the image from the Dockerfile in the cwd
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

Once the `web` container starts, I want to write some content to `/bitnami/tomcat/data/` on the `tomcat_service` container. I tried just writing to that disk location from within the `web` container but am getting an exception:

> No such file or directory: '/bitnami/tomcat/data/'

Does anyone know what I can do to be able to write to the `tomcat_service` container from the `web` container? I'd be very grateful for any advice others can offer on this question!

Comment: Why do you want to write from 1 container to another?

Comment: @jrtapsell I basically want to load a .war file into my tomcat container. The war file is programmatically generated in the `web` container. Should I build tomcat in the `web` container instead? I liked the cleanliness of separate containers via compose, but maybe that's not feasible

Comment: You might be able to use a multistage build to make the war, and then use that to create a tomcat image with it built in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use docker volumes if you want one service to write to other service. If web writes to someFolderName the same file will exist in the tomcat_service.

```
version: '2'

services:

  tomcat_service:
    image: 'bitnami/tomcat:latest'
    volumes:
      - my_shared_data:/bitnami/tomcat/data/

  web:
    volumes:
      - my_shared_data:/someFolderName

volumes:
  my_shared_data:
```

Data in `volumes` persist and they will be available even next time you re-create docker containers. You should always use docker volumes when writing some data in docker containers.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much for your note; I thought the volumes might help here but you've made this much clearer. Just to check: If I `touch /someFolderName/success.json` in `web`, will `tomcat` be able to read `/bitnami/tomcat/data/success.json`?

Comment: yes, you can also mount the volume only for reading to tomcat with `my_shared_data:/bitnami/tomcat/data/:ro`