# Docker - Maria DB wont start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

I have a Windows 10 Pro PC.

I have the following in my docker compose file

```
  database:
image: mariadb:5.5.57
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  - ./sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
  - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_USER=rootUsr
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rootPwd
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=root_db
```

When I run docker-compose up - I get this error in the console

```
 database_1     | InnoDB: 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
database_1     | InnoDB: initial 640 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
consumer_1     | Starting the development server...
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
database_1     | 180324 17:12:47 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Do I need to do anything else to get maria db running in docker?

**Update**
I have tried deleting all the volumes and doing a rebuild but I still get the same error as below

Comment: delete the volumes, you have some "bad" files there or permission issue

Comment: tried that @Mazel, deleted all volumes and rebuilt but still getting the issue as highlighted above

Comment: i mean delete them from the compose file. If i try your code without them it works. So it must be them

Comment: Interesting - I just removed the data volume and it is working now. Permissions issue perhaps?

Comment: did you even read the error that you posted here? :-) you could fix it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459023/docker-write-to-disk-of-linked-container/49463193#49463193

Comment: Yes I did read it - thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted the volumes from the compose file and it worked fine.
**Update**
Tried the same docker compose file on an Amazon EC2 instance and it worked fine the first time around